# How to display List Gotten from Firebase Database and mongoDB simultaneously

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, retrofit, geofire

I'm having an issues implementing Firebase Database and mongoDb, its confusing I know but here is the issue

In my Firebase Database, I implemented geofire, I set the keys of each geofire documents to be the same as the one I used to save each users for mongo db so I can easily access nearby users by their id i.e(objectID == GeoFire key).

Geofire is returning a list now , I tried looping through the list and fetching data from my mongodb server via retrofit (I'm on Kotlin) but every time I only get one user . I have 3 users in the geofire , all within range. I want to fetch their images from my server and I don't want to save the images on Firebase, please help

Comment: Can you share some code so that we can get a better idea about what you're attempting and what might be going wrong?  We can only speculate without it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user20042973 sorry for the delayed response, what I'm trying to say here I'll make it clear because the code is bulky. I'll try to post some code. (1). Imagine I created a document in mongoDb it has an ID, (2) I retrieved the ID from MongoDB and used it to create a geofire Document i.e with the child is the -g and -l attributes.  (3). Now I retrieve all nearby documents documents and store them in a ArrayList as Hashmaps. (4).so I'm retrieving the keys and going back to MongoDB to findByID the documents via for Loop for each. NOW THE QUESTION is? How do I display the results in a recyclerView